# How do I add a button on right side of the toolbar in a UISplitViewController?

Tags: iphone, uisplitviewcontroller, uibarbuttonitem, uitoolbar

Trying to add a button to the right side of the toolbar of the detailviewcontroller in a split-view based app. I used flexible space to get it to the right side. In portrait it works fine, but in landscape (when the menu button disappears), the button gets moved so that half of it is off the screen.

Here's the relevant code (in `DetailViewController.m`):

```
- (void) viewDidLoad 
{
    // initialize toolbar
    toolbar = [[UIToolbar alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectMake( 0, 0, 768, 44 )];
    titleLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectMake( 284, 3, 200, 35 )];
    titleLabel.text = @"Title & Location";
    titleLabel.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter;
    [toolbar addSubview: titleLabel];
    UIBarButtonItem *flexibleSpace = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem: UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace target: nil action: nil];
    UIBarButtonItem *doneButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle: @"Add Event" style: UIBarButtonItemStyleDone target: rootController action: @selector(parseDone)];
    NSArray *buttonArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: flexibleSpace, doneButton, nil];
    [toolbar setItems: buttonArray];
    [doneButton release];
    [flexibleSpace release];
    [self.view addSubview: toolbar];
}
- (void)showRootPopoverButtonItem:(UIBarButtonItem *)barButtonItem 
{
    NSMutableArray *itemsArray = [toolbar.items mutableCopy];
    [itemsArray insertObject: barButtonItem atIndex: 0];
    [toolbar setItems:itemsArray animated:NO];
}
- (void)invalidateRootPopoverButtonItem:(UIBarButtonItem *)barButtonItem 
{
    NSMutableArray *itemsArray = [toolbar.items mutableCopy];
    [itemsArray removeObject:barButtonItem];
    [toolbar setItems:itemsArray animated:NO];
    [itemsArray release];
}
```

Comment: This problem is most likely due to the autoresizing masks. You may wan to check the settings and make sure they are what you mean them to be.

Comment: I had this problem too in the past and I had fixed it somehow, but my memory is like a colander.

Comment: Also, you have asked 14 questions and accepted 0 answers. You may want to go back through older questions and accept (click the check mark beside) the answer that solved your problem. By doing so, you become an active member of the SO community and are more likely to encourage people take the time to try to help you in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well the problem was that I wasn't correctly resizing the toolbar when the iPad rotates to landscape mode. Fixed the problem by add this code:

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
if( interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft || interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight ) {
    [toolbar setFrame: CGRectMake( 0, 0, 700, 44 )];
}
else {
    [toolbar setFrame: CGRectMake( 0, 0, 768, 44 )];
}

return YES;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I recognize this problem from a project I worked on a while back. I think it only happened occasionally and I don't remember if we actually fixed it.

In your case it seems like it would be easier to just use the navigation bar and set `rightBarButtonItem` and `leftBarButtonItem`. That should solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

In fact, if you put your view controller in a UINavigationController you get the UINavigationBar and all the functionality of the navigation controller, if you choose to use it.